# echo the output from a continuous stream

Tags: shell-script, shell

i am executing a command through the bash script and command gives continuous stream of output.

```
echo -e $(  npm start)
```

the problem is echo print only the latest output. How do I get all the stream not the latest one.

Comment: Can you not redirect the npm command to a log and then cat the log file?

Comment: Is that the only option ? the npm command output is countinous , so i don't know when the output ends. The logging  to STDOUT needs to be dynamic.

Comment: The redirect to the file will be continuous. You can then use tail -f to follow an appends to the file.

Comment: Is that the only option? Cause i need to, periodically do tail -f .

Comment: Why the echo at all? Just run `npm run start` and it will print its output on stdout just as it should.

Answer (score 1):

With a command substitution, the shell would need to wait for the command in `$(...)` to completely finish before running the rest of the command line (the `echo -e`).

In this case, you don't need a command substitution:

```
npm run start
```

would produce its output without the help of `echo`.

If you need to have this write to a log file:

```
npm run start >/some/path/log.txt 2>&1
```

This would redirect both standard output and any diagnostic messages to the given log file path.